# Getting through in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I have just completed Machine learning course from Andrew ng and would like to proceed further.
I also want the python implementation of Machine Learning from beginning so that i can practice on Kaggle.
Also, is there any better book or tutorial or some resource like that so that i can proceed further without wasting any time searching such resources.

Comment: ng has a new series: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best book unequivocally that has implementation of Machine Learning algorithms in Python is the "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python: A Guide for Data Scientists" by Andreas C. Müller. Machine Learning algorithms in Python can be used from a package called scikit-learn. This package has everything you need for Machine Learning. All the algorithms, scaling, cross validation. And that book is written by the chief developer of scikit-learn itself.

Comment: Thanks, i just started that book.

Comment: If the answers solves your problem, you hit the TICK mark

Comment: Sorry, I did not know that !!